# .Net Add a table to legacy code

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, legacy-code

I have a legacy code base written in .NET

It has a web.config with various connection strings defined to an oracle database. I have altered its QA environment connection string to point to my own oracle database located in a VM. (The schema of both the database is same)

I am able to use its existing class like XYZDbModelEntity which extends ObjectContext using which I can query existing models like,

```
using(XYZDbModelEntity ctx = new XYZDbModelEntity(EnvironmentAwareSettings.EFDatabaseConnectionString))
{
 info = ctx.SOME_SCHEDULE
           .Include("TIME")
           .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == ID);
}
```

Now I have added a table in the existing database (on my VM) and I need it to be picked up with this application, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.
I have a XYZDbModel.edmx file and a XYZDbModel.tt file that has a lot of .cs files which probably correspond to my tables...

I do not know if I have provided enough information... Any pointers in how to go about doing this will be immensely helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just double click on XYZDbModel.edmx file in Solution Explorer and Entity Model Designer right click on empty space and select Update Model From Database and select the table you need to add.

Comment: Ok. I cannot do that as of now- will give it a try tomorrow. But what will it add, does it add a model in SSDL? And what are the next steps before I can start querying it..? Or is it automatically added in XYZDbModel.tt and picked up in my ctx object as ctx.NEW_TABLE... Thanks for help..

Comment: Clicking Update Model from Database opens up Update Wizard with Choose your Data Connection dialog box. Check this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw3t11olchap4oa/Screenshot%202014-04-20%2018.37.12.png   So I don't want to choose a new connection, I just want it to use the existing one defined in the web.config. The drop down is empty.